# Rails CSV importing where file has headers not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

Lets say one has a model with the following headers ( ID, Name ) but one has a CSV file with additional headers for example, but not limited to ( ID, Name, Price, Location ). How would one change your Model.rb file to skip the headers that doesnt exist?

```
def self.import(file)
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
  product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
  product.save!
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create a new product or edit an existing one. You could add the needed attributes inside the find_or_create_by block.

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    self.find_or_create_by(id: row["id"]) do |product|
      product.name = row["name"]
    end  
  end
end
```

If you only are ever going to need id and name you could do something like this in rails 4.

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    self.where(:id => row["id"], :name => row["name"]).first_or_create
  end
end
```